# Access a static variable in a class

Tags: php

The example below has a syntax error because of the following code:

```
"another_key" => [ 2 => self::$someStr ]
```

Using something such as:

```
"another_key" => [ 2 => "bar" ]
```

Is correct syntax. Is there any way to access $someStr instead of hard coding the string?

```
<?php

class Foo {

  protected static $someStr = 'bar';

  private static $arr = [
    "some_key" => [ 1 ],
    "another_key" => [ 2 => self::$someStr ]
  ];
}
```

Comment: As per the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): `[Property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.` Using `self::$someStr` requires run-time evaluation

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access static variables inside of the declaration of other static variables.  You can either declare a class constant or initialize it by accessing via a function.  A class constant would look like this:

```
class Foo {

  const someStr = 'bar';

  private static $arr = [
    "some_key" => [ 1 ],
    "another_key" => [ 2 => self::someStr ]
  ];
}
```

Or using a function:

```
class Foo {

  private static $someStr = 'bar';

  private static $arr = [
    "some_key" => [ 1 ],
    "another_key" => [ 2 => null ]
  ];

  private static function setKey(){
      self::$arr['another_key'] = [2 => self::$somStr];
  }
}
```

You'd then have to call `Foo::setKey()` at some point before accessing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a property to set the value of another property you should be doing it in the class' constructor. Something like this:

```
class Foo {

    protected static $someStr = 'bar';

    private static $arr = [
        'some_key' => [1]
    ];

    public function __constructor()
    {
        self::arr['another_key'] = [2 => self::$somStr];
    }
}
```

For this to work you will need to instantiate your class.

You can view some examples on property declarations in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: This solution assumes that the class has been instantiated at some point in the stack, since variables are static that isn't necessarily true.